# What is my password for kubuntu?

Tags: password

I just installed kubuntu. What is my password?  I've never entered a password but it won't open to the desktop unless I enter a password.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't enter a password, just try hitting login with the password field blank anyway.

Source: Personal experience, found this thread to back me up: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1064319

Answer (score 0):

If you do not remember the password it asked for during installation, then use another computer (or dual disk drives with the livecd) and burn a copy of hbcd (hiren's boot cd). It has an option to reset ubuntu based distro passwords